# Javascript prompt doesn't work on Nokia Lumia Phones

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, nokia

I have the following javascript code:

```
var author = prompt("Would you give us your name please?", "Anonymous");
```

But the prompt window is never showed. I'm planning to create custom popup for that, but is there any workaround to still use the native browser one.

Actually both alerts below show *undefined*

```
alert(typeof prompt);
alert(typeof window.prompt);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var author = window.prompt("Would you give us your name please?", "Anonymous");
```